# TensorflowJS takes too long

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

When I run TensorflowJS on the browser, especially on the phone, it takes really long to predict and sometimes doesn't even work. I'm using the optimized graph already. I want to know if there is any way to speed it up, whether by running a prediction before the page loads so that the second is faster or anything else.

I am using InceptionV3 architecture, and the image size is 299 by 299; if I could make that smaller perhaps it could go faster, but that would mean I would have to retrain my model. Note: I am not training using Tensorflowjs, only making predictions. Here is the relevant code:

```
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var file = ctx.getImageData(0,0,120,120);
    const raw = tf.fromPixels(file).toFloat();
    const resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear(raw, [299, 299])
    const offset = tf.scalar(127);
    const normalized = resized.sub(offset).div(offset);
    batched = normalized.expandDims(0);
    f = model.execute(batched).dataSync();
```

Comment: Indeed, it might take long to run it your batch size has lots of data. Having said that it will be easier to tell about the optimization you can make if we can see the relevant part of the code you wrote

Comment: Sure, I'll show it in the next answer. The problem is that I am only predicting 1 image, and ai did not expect it to take that long.

Comment: I have added the relevant code to my question.

Comment: Try using mobilenet instead of inception.  It's much smaller and faster and designed for such applications

Comment: @BlessedKey thanks for the advice! I have, and it works perfectly. Unfortunately, the overall accuracy was smaller, and thus I can't use this architecture. Currently trying to optimize the graph for deployment, but am having trouble with it.

Comment: If you have additional data, you should be able to retrain another layer on top of the mobilenet output.  I believe there is an example of this in tfjs-examples

Comment: @BlessedKey I have, and the precision is still low; I used the Tensorflow retrain.py method.

Comment: Ah, just so I understand, retraining on inception meets your quality threshold, but retraining on mobilenet does not?

Comment: @BlessedKey Yes! Exactly.